# What is the preferred way of saving dynamic lists in database?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

In our application user can create different lists (like sharepoint) for example a user can create a list of cars (name, model, brand) and a list of students (name, dob, address, nationality), e.t.c.

Our application should be able to query on different columns of the list so we can't just serialize each row and save it in one row.

Should I create a new table at runtime for each newly created list? If this was the best solution then probably Microsoft SharePoint would have done it as well I suppose?

Should I use the following schema

```
Lists (Id, Name)
ListColumns (Id, ListId, Name)
ListRows (Id, ListId)
ListData(RowId, ColumnId, Value)
```

Though a single row will create as many rows in list data table as there are columns in the list, this just doesn't feel right.

Have you dealt with this situation? How did you handle it in database?

Comment: Not bad at all, but often the convention is to not use plural.  That is table names are normally List, ListColumn, ListRow, ListData.  Tables have more than one row, using plural is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a potential solution would be the creating of lists can involve `CREATE TABLE` statements for those entities/lists?

It sounds like the db structure or schema can change at runtime, or at the user's command, so perhaps something like this might help?

- User wants to create a new list of an entity never seen before. Call it Computer.
- User defines the attributes (screensize, CpuSpeed, AmountRAM, NumberOfCores)
- System allows user to create in the UI
- system generally lets them all be strings, unless can tell when all supplied values are indeed dates or numbers.
- build the CREATE scripts, execute them against the DB.
- insert the data that the user defined into that new table.

Properly coded, we're working with the requirements given: *let users create new entities*. There was no mention of scale here. Of course, this requires all input to be sanitized, queries parameterized, actions logged, etc.

The negative comment below doesn't actually give any good reasons, but creates a bit of FUD. I'd be interested in addressing any concerns with this *potential solution*. We haven't heard about scale, security, performance, or usage (internal LAN vs. internet).

Comment: Really?  This sounds like a horrible idea to me -- in so many ways.

Comment: Please, please don't do this. I've never seen a good case for programatically creating tables, and this certainly doesn't sell me on it. What happens if two users want to create a list with the same name? What you want is a table. Call it `lists`. Proceed from there.

Comment: @Hogan @meagar Assuming that each user is working with their own personal database this sounds like the best solution to me - sure having a `lists` table might *seem* like a nice "pure" solution to the problem but have you ever tried writing a query to join across multiple "tables" when all the data is really in 1 physical table?  Not to mention that you can give up on any hopes you had on having it actually perform.

Comment: @Kragen: Of course I had to solve this problem.  It is a problem which has come up in all most every project I've worked on.  I've also taken over projects set up like you are doing and it is a nightmare.  After this project you will do it the right way next time... you are in for a wold of hurt.

Answer (score 2):

what you did is called [EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value Model)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model).

For a list with 3 columns and 1000 entries:

1 record in Lists
3 records in ListColumns
and 3000 Entries in ListData

This is fine. I'm not a fan of creating tables on-the-fly because it could mess up your database and you would have to "generate" your SQL queries dynamically. I would get a strange feeling when users could CREATE/DROP/ALTER Tables in my database!

Another nice feature of the EAV model is that you could merge two lists easily without droping and altering a table.

**Edit:**

I think you need another table called ListRows that tells you which ListData records belong together in a row!

Comment: +1 for this answer. It gets the job done, and it's flexible! I'd watch for perf or scale issues in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Well I've experienced something like this before - I don't want to share the actual table schema so lets do some thought exercises using some of the suggested table structures:

- Lets have a `lists` table containing a list of all my lists
- Lets also have a `columns` table containing the metadata (column names)
- Now we need a `values` table which contains the column values
- We also need a `rows` table which contains a list of all the rows, otherwise it gets very difficult to work out how many rows there actually are

To keep things simple lets just make everything a string (`VARCAHR`) and have a go at coming up with some queries:

**Counting all the rows in a table**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [rows]
JOIN [lists]
    ON [rows].list_id = [Lists].id
WHERE [Lists].name = 'Cars'
```

Hmm, not too bad, compared to:

```
SELECT * FROM [Cars]
```

**Inserting a row into a table**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @row_id INT
DECLARE @list_id INT

SELECT @list_id = id FROM [lists] WHERE name = 'Cars'

INSERT INTO [rows] (list_id) VALUES (@list_id)
SELECT @row_id = @@IDENTITY

DECLARE @column_id INT

-- === Need one of these for each column ===
SELECT @column_id = id FROM [columns]
WHERE name = 'Make'
AND list_id = @list_id

INSERT INTO [values] (column_id, row_id, value)
VALUES (@column_id, @row_id, 'Rover')

-- === Need one of these for each column ===
SELECT @column_id = id FROM [columns]
WHERE name = 'Model'
AND list_id = @list_id

INSERT INTO [values] (column_id, row_id, value)
VALUES (@column_id, @row_id, 'Metro')
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Um, starting to get a little bit hairy compared to:

```
INSERT INTO [Cars] ([Make], [Model}) VALUES ('Rover', 'Metro')
```

**Simple queries**

I'm now getting bored of constructing tediously complex SQL statements so maybe you can have a go at coming up with equivalent queries for the followng statements:

```
SELECT [Model] FROM [Cars] WHRE [Make] = 'Rover'

SELECT [Cars].[Make], [Cars].[Model], [Owners].[Name] FROM [Cars]
JOIN [Owners] ON [Owners].id = [Cars].owner_id
WHERE [Owners].Age > 50

SELECT [Cars].[Make], [Cars].[Model], [Owners].[Name] FROM [Cars]
JOIN [Owners] ON [Owners].id = [Cars].owner_id
JOIN [Addresses] ON [Addresses].id = [Owners].address_id
WHERE [Addresses].City = 'London'
```

I hope you are beginning to get the idea...

In short - I've experienced this before and I can assure you that creating a database inside a database in this way is definitely a Bad Thing.

If you need to do **anything** but the most basic querying on these lists (and literally I mean "Can I have all the items in this list please?"), you should try and find an alternative.

As long as each user pretty much has their own database I'll definitely recommend the `CREATE TABLE` approach.  Even if they don't I'd still recommend that you at least consider it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have Sharepoint already deployed in your environment.

Consider integrating your application with Sharepoint, and have it be your datastore. No need to recreate all the things you like about Sharepoint, when you could leverage it.

It'd take a bit of configuring, but you could call SP web services to CRUD your list data for you.

- [inserting list data into Sharepoint via web services](http://benreichelt.net/blog/2006/3/25/Insert-a-Sharepoint-list-item-from-web-services/)
- [reading SP lists via web services](http://dotnetdreamer.com/2009/06/04/moss-web-services-accessing-sharepoint-list-data/)

Sharepoint 2010 can also expose lists via OData, which would be simple to consume from any application.

Comment: We can't have half a database live in sql server and the rest in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely not dynamically create tables when your users create lists. That isn't how databases are meant to work.

Your schema is correct, and the pluralization is, in my opinion, also correct, though I would remove the camel case and call them `lists`, `list_columns`, `list_rows` and `list_data`.

I would further improve upon your schema by skipping `rows` and `columns` tables, they serve no purpose. Simply have a row/column number attached to each cell, and keep things sparse: Don't bother holding empty cells in the database. You retain the ability to query/sort based on row/column, your queries will be (potentially very much) faster because the number of `list_cells` will be reduced, and you won't have to do any crazy joining to link your data back to its table.

Here is the complete schema:

```
create table lists (
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(25) not null
);

create table list_cells (
  id int primary key,
  list_id int not null references lists(id)
    on delete cascade on update cascade,
  row int not null,
  col int not null,
  data varchar(25) not null
);
```